# XCB STRING and WM_NAME not defined

Tags: c++, c, x11, xcb

Where are `STRING` and `WM_NAME` defined?

My `xcb_atom.h` file only contains 3 function declarations, when I was expecting it to look like this: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/X11libs/X11libs-40/xcb-util/xcb-util-0.3.3/atom/xcb_atom.h

I also have a `xcb_ewmh.h` file that contains similar atoms but I cannot find any documentation on it.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I grepped my `/usr/include/xcb` directory:

```
$ grep -r WM_NAME
xproto.h:    XCB_ATOM_WM_NAME
```

So, they're defined in `xproto.h`, which is included by the following:

```
$ grep -l -r xproto.h
xvmc.h
shape.h
shm.h
xselinux.h
render.h
glx.h
xcb.h
screensaver.h
xtest.h
xkb.h
sync.h
xinerama.h
res.h
composite.h
damage.h
xprint.h
xv.h
xfixes.h
xinput.h
randr.h
dri2.h
```

Answer (score 7):

As noted in the other answer, the symbols are in `xproto.h` which is dragged in by `xcb.h`, but are not named as in the XCB tutorial. You need to use `XCB_ATOM_WM_NAME` and `XCB_ATOM_WM_STRING`.

Comment: This was helpful, but it's actuall `XCB_ATOM_STRING` not `XCB_ATOM_WM_STRING`.